# Where is "txt.cfg"?

Tags: lubuntu, configuration, persistence

I'm using Lubuntu 12.10 on a USB stick but it is not persistent.

Instructions on how to make it persistent are in this thread:

[Why isn't persistence working on Lubuntu 12.04 Live-USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168246/why-isnt-persistence-working-on-lubuntu-12-04-live-usb?rq=1)

But I can find neither a directory `syslinux` nor a file called `txt.cfg` or `syslinux.cfg`

(I have, for example, used the command `find / txt.cfg` at the `$` prompt)

Where is the configuration file for Lubuntu 12.10? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Look in the isolinux directory on the usb stick.  The file txt.cfg exists there.  Your find command probably needed the -name switch in front of the txt.cfg.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Can't find "isolinux" either. (Actually I did use -name when using the find command; forgot that only when writing my post. ;-)

Comment: But I most likely confused myself by not using -name consistently...

Answer (score 1):

First answer: in my case it is in the subdirectory "syslinux" in the directory "cdrom".

Thanks to all concerned!

Answer (score 0):

My own second answer:

1) Although I applied what was suggested at the end of the thread mentioned before,

[Why isn't persistence working on Lubuntu 12.04 Live-USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168246/why-isnt-persistence-working-on-lubuntu-12-04-live-usb?rq=1) ,

my first lubuntu installation is still not persistent.

2) I used the existing USB installation as a springboard to install lubuntu on another (larger) USB stick. No problems with the installation process, but the new installation is also not persistent. And even more interesting, I cannot find either of the following files or directories (as before, using the command "sudo find / -name [...]":

syslinux, isolinux, txt.cfg, text.cfg

(someone less sanguine than myself might perhaps insert some swear words here)

Note: as with the first installation, there is a directory "cdrom" in the root - but with the second installation it is shown as empty.

Back to the original question...

Comment: I wrote, "new installation is also not persistent". To refine that statement: my choices of Monitor Settings & Desktop Preferences have to be reset after every reboot, while the settings of Network Connections & Time and Date stay the same. Language Suport settings change within limits: the languages I have selected don't change, but during a reboot the order I choose is being reset to what lubuntu thinks it should be. I have removed the Chromium browser and replaced it with Firefox, so I don't know whether Chromium settings would survive a reboot now or not, but at least Firefox settings do.

Comment: Also, there is no "casper" to be found now, so I may as well forget about "txt.cfg" (it looks like the new installation is an altogether different kind of animal, and the degree of "persistency" it has is perhaps good enough, considering that the USB stick is only an emergency tool - to tie me over until I've found a fix for the boot problem with Windows - and not meant for daily use).

Answer (score 0):

You are better off installing Lubuntu onto another USB stick.
The 'live' is not really meant to be permanent, it's for trial usage and as an installer to another drive. It's better to use it to install to an ext4 partition on another stick.

http://humpty.drivehq.com/blogs/linux/moving.html#Install_Lubuntu