# Persistence is not working on Lubuntu live (USB)

Tags: lubuntu, live-usb, persistence

I am unable to set up persistence on my Lubuntu. The settings never save and the files I stock on any partition get deleted. I've been trying Rufus, Unetbootin, rufus then trying to partitionate manually in Windows 10 and same with Unetbootin (and the precedent way in linux too). I sometime got a new Volume that apeared, but I know there is somethings missing (like a casper-rw file & modifications in some files, I think).
I don't know how I can solve that. I've been able to read little about similar problems, but it was always missing steps(or error 404).

I would like to get help please. Could you please write and explain completely the steps to solve my problem. I have some good knowledge on Linux but I wish it will be clear for me as I've seen one solution with uncompleted bash commands and missing steps...
I would be very grateful!

Comment: You haven't mentioned which Lubuntu (modern or legacy), but the Lubuntu team recommend `mkusb` (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Persistent_live_systems)   The starting point is your release (there are 3 supported *installers* for Lubuntu, and thus the release & ISO in question does matter; 2 of the 3 have been tested & work; the third makes no sense being used in that way)

Comment: It's the newest Lubuntu

Comment: So if I download live ubuntu then use mkusb to create persistent lubuntu live, it is supported thus working?

Comment: Your question needs to be more specific. You did not specify a release (which one is "newest?" Are you sure?) You did not link to any instructions that you followed (maybe they were unofficial or ancient). Alternately, you did not list the steps that you followed. You did not provide any troubleshooting details beyond "it didn't work". If you encountered any errors, you did not mention them. Help us to help you.

Comment: The most recent Lubuntu is 20.04 LTS
I found very few pages with problems looking alike, for example:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/168246/why-isnt-persistence-working-on-lubuntu-12-04-live-usb

But I can't procede because the files are unexistant/different.
When I tried different creators, I saved files on desktop and in the new created partition I named "casper-rw". They always disapeared at reboot. I tried modifying some .cfg files with what I understood about a site (write "persistent" everytime you see "--" at the end).

Comment: Lubuntu 20.04 isn't the latest; 20.04.1 is later (and it's not the latest ISO released either; 18.04.5 was released a week after 20.04.1 so details matter). The question you linked was for a much older `ubiquity` ISO, I'd instead suggest https://askubuntu.com/questions/1283839/how-do-i-make-my-live-ubuntu-on-a-usb-stick-persistant/1283905#1283905 which links to another too if needed

Comment: That's about all I found.

Comment: I know there are many reasons it doesn't work so that's why I am asking here to get help to solve my problem.

Comment: I think from 20.04 the persistence partition/file has to be named `writable`

Comment: My first link is how it was tested & proven to work by the Lubuntu team itself, why I started with the `mkusb` link.  If you're patient one of the maintainers of `mkusb` may see & respond to this with knowledge far beyond me (I've already linked to a tester again with more knowledge & understanding than me). Until then I've provided where I'd look...

Comment: So if I follow the steps on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb in Ubuntu OS, I will be able to make a persistent live USB with my lubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso ?

Comment: That has been tested & works.  It's tested numerous times during development (to ensure no issues have changed; which has been numerous times during the current *groovy* development cycle), but yes it's been tested & works.  I'd verify your ISO is valid as per manual; https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.1/retrieving_the_image.html

Comment: I'll get back to you on that! Let's test it

Comment: Also maybe useful, https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/create-persistent-usb-with-manual-install/1498/2 which leads you to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181854/how-is-it-easier-to-make-a-persistent-live-drive-with-ubuntu-19-10  (*you'll note answer was updated last on 20.04 release even though written for 19.10*)

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity: For Ubuntu 20.04 a **persistent file** must be named `writable` a **persistent partition** can be named either `writable` or `casper-rw`. A separate persistent home file or partition can be named `home-rw`.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Sorry to annoy you with this, I'm developing my own multiboot usb software, if you are interested to check on it, in my profile there's a contact mail.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity That email address is not working for me.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Now it's fixed.

Answer (score 2):

### Simple Hand Made Persistent USB

This exercise should show you how to build a Persistent USB from the ground up. It has a casper-rw/writable Persistence partition, a NTFS/FAT32 Data partition and will boot in either BIOS or UEFI mode. It can be easily modified to multiboot etc.

- Boot Installed Ubuntu or Live USB.
- Insert Target USB.
- Start GParted.
- Create a GPT partition table on Target USB.
- Create a 1MB BIOS boot partition on the left, formatted as unformatted.
- Add a 300MB FAT32 EFI boot partition next to it.
- Add an ext4 root partition large enough for the Ubuntu ISO's contents, (~ 3GB for 20.04).
- Create an ext4 partition labeled casper-rw
- Add a NTFS data partition if desired.
- Apply all operations.
- Flag partition 1 bios_grub.
- Flag Partition 2 boot, esp
- Close GParted.

[image: gparted]

- Open the ISO's folder as Administrator, open the ISO using Archive Manager.
- Extract the ISO's contents to the Target's root partition.
- Drag and drop the boot and EFI folders from Archive Manager window to the EFI boot partition.
- Edit sdx2/boot/grub/grub.cfg adding set root=(hd0,3) after the "Try Ubuntu ..." line.
- Add a space and the word "persistent" after ---.

[image: grub.cfg]

- Install grub, if in BIOS mode or booted from Live USB drive run:

  ```
    sudo mount /dev/sdx2 /mnt

    sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sdx
  ```
- If in UEFI mode on installed system, boot into the Target drive and run the above commands.

*Booting based on mkusb by sudodus